# SSIS- New Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have one text file which have 4 columns and I have to create 9 column from it.

example

Input

```
id,
no,
product, 
quantity
```

Derived column

```
id, 
no,
product, 
quantity,
id_out,
no_out,
product_out, 
quantity_out,
Type
```

Here I took all four Out rows form inputs but Type is not related to Input. It will filled by reference text files later on.
So could you please tell me how I can add new column?

Appreciate your efforts.

Thank You,

343

Comment: Which Column are you trying to add?  You mentioned Deriving a column, which can be done in a transformation.  Are you going to breakout and substring one of your current inputs to use for the other columns?  Do you have another input that you're going to join to?  Your question is somewhat unclear...

Comment: you can add new column `Type` when it is read from reference text files, why do you need that before you read that data?

Answer (score 0):

You can select NULL values if you just want the structure

```
  SELECT id, 
           no,
           product, 
           quantity,
           NULL as [id_out],
           NULL as [no_out],
           NULL as [product_out], 
           NULL as [quantity_out],
           NULL as [Type]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got by using Null operator...Thanks for your effort.